# How do I get the Full Name of attendees on a calendar invite within Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to iterate through the list of attendees, both required and optional. I have a Power Automate that is correctly getting

However, instead of the email addresses, I would like to get the Full Names

I tried this to convert the string into an array, to then iterate and use 'Get User Profile V2' to get the 'Display Name'

This doesn't seem to work

```
@{items('Apply_to_each_Calendar_Event')?['requiredAttendees']}.split(';')
```

What I'm wanting is to do the following:

go from a string containing: email1@test.com;email2@test.com

Ultimately to put into a variable to look like:

```
[[First Last1]]
[[First Last2]]
```

Where the full name found from Get User Profile from email1@test.com will return 'First Last1' and email2@test.com will return 'First Last2' respectively.

Snippet from the flow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize an array prior to your loop and split it there.

This is the expression that's in the second step below ...

```
split(variables('Email Addresses'), ';')
```

... with PowerAutomate, it's not a programming language so the dot notation doesn't work, you need to use formula based expressions.

This is a basic mock up of what I'm talking about ...

[image: Flow]

**Result**

[image: Result]